# ODE without solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible to find functions $a,b,c$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$, such that
\begin{equation*}
ay'+by=c
\end{equation*}
has no global solution and $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are never both zero ?

If $c=0$ there is always $y=0$ but I don't know about the general case. I think there is always a solution but I don't know how to prove it and it doesn't fall into the Cauchy-Lipschitz realm.

My question comes from the theory of pasting solutions: when $a(x)$ is zero the affine subset of solutions can be of dimension 0,1,2 according as to how solutions of homogenous equations paste around the singularity. I wonder if it can be empty.

The condition on $a$ and $b$ is to avoid trickery counter-examples like $x^3y'+3x^2y=2x$ whose solutions $y=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{\lambda}{x^3}$ are not global.

Comment: If you do not have any restrictions on the functions a,b,c then it is. It is enough to consider $\text{dom}(a)\cap\text{dom}(b)\cap\text{dom}(c)=\emptyset$.

Comment: @PavelR. I wasn't precise enough, I edited to take into account your remark.

Answer (score 1):

If $a(x)\ne 0$, then this is not posible. The general solution is
$$
y= \int\frac{c(x)}{a(x)} \exp\left(\int\dfrac{b(x)}{a(x)}\, dx\right)\, dx\;\cdot\;
\exp\left(-\int\dfrac{b(x)}{a(x)}\, dx\right),
$$
or, if we denote as $G(x)$ some antiderivative
of $\frac{b(x)}{a(x)}$ and as $F(x)$ some antiderivative of $\frac{c(x)}{a(x)} \exp\left(G(x)\right)$,
$$\tag{1}
y=(F(x)+C)\cdot \exp(-G(x))=C \exp(-G(x))+F(x)\exp(-G(x)).
$$
Indeed,
$$
y'= C \exp(-G(x))(-G'(x))+F'(x)\exp(-G(x))+
F(x)\exp(-G(x))(-G'(x))
$$
$$
=-C \frac{b(x)}{a(x)}\exp(-G(x))+\frac{c(x)}{a(x)} \exp\left(G(x)\right)\exp(-G(x))-\frac{b(x)}{a(x)}
F(x)\exp(-G(x));
$$
substituting this into the original equation, one obtains
$$
-C b(x)\exp(-G(x))+c(x) -b(x)
F(x)\exp(-G(x))
+C b(x) \exp(-G(x))+b(x)F(x)\exp(-G(x))=c(x).
$$
Consider the initial value problem
$$
a(x)y'+b(x)y=c(x),\quad y(x_0)=y_0.
$$
For any the initial point $(x_0,y_0)$ from (1) we have
$$\tag{2}
y_0=C \exp(-G(x_0))+F(x_0)\exp(-G(x_0))
$$
For any $(x_0,y_0)$ the corresponding constant $C$ can be found:
$$
C=\exp(G(x_0))\left( y_0- F(x_0)\exp(-G(x_0)) \right),
$$
thus, (1) gives a solution for any initial point. Hence, it is a general solution.

Finally, note that (1) gives us a continuous function because the antiderivative of a continuous function is continuous. Hence, the solution is globally defined.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but my interest lies precisely in the case $a(x)=0$. I'll add some motivation as to why in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=x,b=1$ and $c=2x$ for positive $x$, $c=0$ for negative $x$.
Then $y=\frac{\lambda}{x}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{*}_{-}$ and $y=x+\frac{\mu}{x}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}$, so the only hope for pasting is $\lambda=\mu=0$ but then $y$ wouldn't be differentiable in $0$.

Another example can be obtained with $c=\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{|x|}$ where again $y=\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{x}$ is not differentiable in $0$.

Differentiability fails in both examples, but continuity doesn't. If I am not mistaken you can prove (by using the explicit formulae given by AVK) that there is always a solution that extends by continuity to the zero of $A$ (but there may be pasting problems for several zeroes).